# Why is my answer Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8869200/99456) on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697085/win32console-installed-doesnt-require-as-expected) is Community Wiki, but I didn't edit my answer 10 times, nor I checked "community wiki" checkbox.

Is there a particular reason why it became wiki when I posted it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yax, the answer's [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8869200/revisions) shows that you made it Community Wiki yourself:

> Post Made Community Wiki by Yax - occurred 21 mins ago

You can flag your answer for moderator attention, explain that it was made CW by mistake and ask for the CW status to be removed.

Comment: I must have made it by mistake. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Also, [that revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8869200/revisions) implicitly shows you clicked the checkbox while editing in the 5 minute grace period (the time in which edits do not create a new revision), @Yax. When clicking it before saving it the first time, [the notice is below the post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/119149/revisions), in the revision history.

Answer (score 3):

Just testing to see if you get any alert when mistakenly checking the "community wiki" box..

Nope - no alert at all so it might be good idea to post Feature Request asking to add such alert as this can't be undone and people tend to do mistakes.

Comment: That feature request exists: [Are you sure you want to make this community wiki?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36142/are-you-sure-you-want-to-make-this-community-wiki)

Comment: @Arjan thanks, looks like it won't get implemented any time soon, the community itself pretty much declined it. Oh well.. :)

Comment: Well, *maybe* the community downvoted that as the question itself is kind of bad. On the other hand: [the question started okay](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/36142/1); maybe we should rollback!

Comment: @Arjan well the OP isn't really active here anymore so it might be good idea. :)