# Why was a particular SO answer converted to 'Community Wiki' when only the author had edited it?

Tags: support, community-wiki

Way back in the dim distant mists of time (October 2008, which may render this unanswerable), I wrote an answer to:

- [Solve the memory alignment in C interview question that stumped me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227897/solve-the-memory-alignment-in-c-interview-question-that-stumped-me/227900#227900)

I edited the answer 6 times it was made Community Wiki.  The question is not CW. This seems to disagree with the rules elaborated in:

- [My answer got converted to Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57971/my-answer-got-converted-to-community-wiki) (July 2010).

Going through that list:

1. *The body of the post has been edited six (6) times by at least four (4) different people.*

   No; 2 people; 7 by me in Oct and Nov 2008 and 1 by someone else (and the other person's edit was in Feb 2012).
2. *The post has been edited eight (8) times by the original owner.*

   No.
3. *The post's author checks the community wiki checkbox when composing the question or answer.*

   The conversion took effect some 20 days(!) after the sixth edit.
4. *The post is edited by its original author, who when doing so opts to check the community wiki.*

   I don't think I made that mistake.  (The annotation is "Post Made Community Wiki by Community♦", not the "Post Made Community Wiki by Jonathan Leffler" which this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119146/why-is-my-answer-community-wiki) suggests would have been recorded if I'd made the mistake.)
5. *An answer posted to a Community Wiki question will also be Community Wiki.*

   No; the question is not CW.
6. *The question generates more than 30 answers.*

   No; 12 answers.
7. *A moderator has reason to believe that the question serves better in community wiki mode.*

   Strictly N/A since the question is not CW.

Were the rules sufficiently different back in October and November 2008 or was there a mistake?  (Subtext: *Can I have the gold badge and reputation I've not received since the answer was made CW?*)

Comment: The question you refer to is almost four years old.  The rules were different back then, especially the way CW was stamped in the edit history.  My vote is binding, so rather than just closing your question I'll cast my hand-waving *"Too Localized"* vote.

Comment: And no, you can't have the reputation back.  Even if we removed the CW flag now, the votes were cast during the time the question *was* CW, and the system knows that.

Comment: OK; I didn't expect much chance of getting anything changed.  It's a nuisance - mild nuisance - though.  I hadn't realized how many votes it had got because it is CW so I'm never notified.  Ah well.